# How can I limit the range of parameters in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

So normally in pytorch, there is no strict limit to the parameters in models, but what if I wanted them to stay in the range [0,1]? Is there a way to block the update of parameters to outside that range?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A trick used in some generative adversarial networks (some of which require the parameters of the discriminator to be within a certain range) is to clamp the values after every gradient update. For example:

```
model = YourPyTorchModule()

for _ in range(epochs):
    loss = ...
    optimizer.step()
    for p in model.parameters():
        p.data.clamp_(-1.0, 1.0)
```